# Login to Zoho reports via a post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, security

We have been able to automatically login users into Zoho with the following code until very recently.  It appears that they are now requiring a new parameter that looks like this:

iamcsrcoo=1c25c9851ea8a8344c61f8173ae2804fff39610fbddac4cbf2ad69295d6fdb0bc0fa6ee7669afc1ad9fcb4df47463043d92bf8b33dd374f7d18efc17521023dc

If I manually open a browser and cut and paste the value of this variable into the submit routine, it will work in the browser that I grabbed it from.  However, if I try to login with another browser it will not work. I have not been able to determine what it is, or be able to fetch the value prior to submitting the for due to cross-site scripting security.

Any ideas of how I can do this with client or server side scripting?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#login').trigger("click"); 
    });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p></p>
    <form action="https://accounts.zoho.com/login" method="post">

    <input id="LOGIN_ID" name="LOGIN_ID" value="xxx@yahoo.com">
    <input id="PASSWORD" name="PASSWORD" value="passwordgoeshere">
    <input id="servicename" name="servicename" value="ZohoReports">
    <input id="serviceurl" name="serviceurl" value="https://reports.zoho.com">  
    <input id="login" type="submit" >

    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, Here's how I got that variable:

```
#Get Cookie
wget --delete-after --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies=login.dat --header="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1;WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0" https://accounts.zoho.com/login?servicename=ZohoCRM

#Save The 'iamcsr' Cookie
THE_COOKIE="$(cut -f 6-7 login.dat | grep iamcsr | cut -f 2)"

#Get the desired page
wget -O 'login.txt' --load-cookies login.dat --header="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" --post-data "LOGIN_ID={my@email.com}&PASSWORD={myPassword}&IS_AJAX=true&iamcsrcoo=$THE_COOKIE" https://accounts.zoho.com/login?servicename=ZohoCRM
```